# Russian in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cyrillic

I need to know how can I enable Russian cyrillic script in my VS10 for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type it with your keyboard.
Visual Studio uses Unicode everywhere by default.

Comment: OK, I have got it, but how can I see other people writings in Russian on my VS10?

Comment: Well, I have obtained some code from some Russian site, and the comments are all in Russian, and I can't read a single line, 'cause it's all wrapped with this "ñîäåðæàùåå âðåìÿ" nonsense. Any advice on that? :)

Comment: That means that the site has the wrong encoding.  Try UTF8 or a Russian ASCII encoding (in the browser menu)

Comment: No, site is just fine, but the comments in my code are not readable, but you gave me an idea to try to change the encoding to UTF8 and see what happens then. :)